# Does the following ring any alarm bells? - $("body div div span #foo:eq(0)")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I understand this is quite a specific way of selecting a node using (i'm assuming) jQuery and selecting an ID would probably be more performant. But apart from that and it being a long selector, what else rings 'alarm bells' here?

I'm asking because i've seen this question on a few job sites now and i'm just trying to understand if there is more to this than meets the eye and if it should ever come up in an interview, i'd understand how to respond.

Saw question here: http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/senior-web-developer/29234531

Comment: You are assuming your HTML structure will never change `body div div ...`... huge alarm bell.

Comment: @KevBot would be bigger if it was `div>div`

Comment: `#id`s should be unique.

Comment: Code implies there *will* be multiple elements with the same `id`

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

- It's too specific
- It's very fragile to HTML structure changes
- It uses an `id` (meant to be unique per page) but qualifies it with other selectors, which should be unnecessary. Sometimes it is necessary when a JS file runs on multiple pages, but that's generally a bad design.
- It uses `:eq(0)` which kills the performance because the selector can't be handed off to `document.querySelectorAll()`
- The returned element should only be one element anyway due to `id` being used.

It should simply be `$('#foo')`, which will be passed straight to `document.getElementById()` (unless Sizzle has changed since I last read the source) or simply the native DOM API.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things jump out at me:

1. `#foo:eq(0)` - The `:eq(0)` is almost certainly entirely unnecessary. `:eq` means "the element in the matching set at this index" and of course there can only be one element with a given ID. So immediately I flag up: Does the overall thing use duplicate IDs in the same document?
2. The supposedly-unnecessary `:eq(0)` is also the only part of the selector that isn't standard CSS, and thus it forces jQuery to process the selector in Sizzle (its own engine) rather than letting the browser do it. Is it likely to cause a performance problem? No (or rather: worry about it if and when it does), but it's pointless.
3. The `body` part is completely pointless.
4. Whenever I see an ID selector as a descendant in a selector, it immediately makes me wonder if the author really understood the rules for IDs in documents (this is sort of related to #1, but slightly different). It's true that that selector **is not** the same as simply `#foo`; the critical being that `#foo` will find the `#foo` element wherever it exists, whereas that selector will only find it **if** it's inside a span inside a div inside a div. So while using a descendant selector effectively ending with an ID selector *can* be valid (if you want to ignore the element if it's not where you're expecting it to be), it's a real edge case. In a code review, I'd want to see a comment saying *why* that was necessary.

So in short, I'd want a **really** good reason from the author for why it wasn't simply `$("#foo")`.

Comment: ...er, um, and fragility, as [alex pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37926589/157247). How did I miss flagging up fragility?